# How to keep typings and not overwrite mongoose models

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I am using mongoose with nextjs and typescript, and this is my setup thus far:

```
//User.ts
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";

// 1. Create an interface representing a document in MongoDB.

export interface IUserAccountData {
  user_uuid: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  address: string;
}

// 2. Create a Schema corresponding to the document interface.
const userAcountDataSchema = new Schema<IUserAccountData>({
  user_uuid: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
});

// 3. Create a Model.
const UserAccountData = model<IUserAccountData>("UserAccountData", userAcountDataSchema);

export { UserAccountData };
```

I can get typings when I use the model within index.tsx:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const client = await connectMongo();
  const userDoc: IUserAccountData = {
    address: "",
    user_uuid: "id",
    email: "email",
    password: "secure",
  };
  const user = UserAccountData.create({
    
  });
  
  return {
    props: {},
  };
}
```

But I receive this error:

```
Server Error

OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `UserAccountData` model once compiled.
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source

lib/models/User.ts (19:48) @ eval

  17 | 
  18 | // 3. Create a Model.
> 19 | const UserAccountData = model<IUserAccountData>("UserAccountData", userAcountDataSchema);
     |                                              ^
  20 | 
  21 | async function run() {
  22 | // 4. Connect to MongoDB
```

To fix this I do this:

```
const UserAccountData = mongoose.models.UserAccountData || model<IUserAccountData>("UserAccountData", userAcountDataSchema);
```

But when doing this I lose typing on the model. I tried manually adding the type but am not able to figure it out:

```
const UserAccountData: (typeof  model<IUserAccountData>) = mongoose.models.UserAccountData || model<IUserAccountData>("UserAccountData", userAcountDataSchema);
```

So help being able to not overwrite the model and still receive typing would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, I was using the wrong `model` object, this is it:

```
const UserAccountData: mongoose.Model<IUserAccountData> =
  mongoose.models.UserAccountData ||
  model<IUserAccountData>("UserAccountData", userAcountDataSchema);
```